# Check whether Celery worker has been executed

Tags: celery

I use the command to start worker

```
celery -A image-classification-task worker --loglevel=info
```

But how do I check whether it has been executed previously and I do not need to reexecute it?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do is to run `celery -A image-classification-task status` - it will show you status of your Celery cluster. If you see a worker running on your local machine (the one you execute the above command on) that means that do not need to start the worker again. Or just run something like `ps aux | grep celery` and see if you have a worker running...